# Chat message history missing window title

Tags: bug, chat

The chat message history windows lack a title. To reproduce, visit https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/5379827/history (or another message history page) and observe lack of title.

Comment: Unrelated to your bug report - I doubt that flags have very much nutritional value.  Remember to have your flags **with** a well-balanced meal at breakfast, lunch, and supper.

Comment: Just joking.  I was referencing the specific chat message you linked to, "*fossfreedom: hungry ... eats flags for breakfast, lunch and supper*"

Comment: Yes, I can see that the page doesn't have a title.

Comment: +1  `document.title` is `''` (blank string) on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; this is a bug.

Possible titles:

- `message history | chat.stackexchange.com` if you want something really short, or
- `"The message truncated to a reasonable len..." | history | chat.stackexchange.com` for a longer one.

(Lowercase for consistency with other Chat `<title>`s.)